# MySQL binlog reading

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I installed MySQL 5.5 on Windows 7 I did it as a general install. All my logs are stored under the C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\mysql-bin.00057 for example

when I try to run mysqlbinlog mysqlbin.000057 it gives me error 2 file not found

I have even tried mysqlbinlog C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\mysql-bin.000057 it also says it can't find the file.

Just wondering how I can use the binlog to read these files using mysqlbinlog

Comment: What if you cd to directory first? cd C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data

Answer (score 0):

MySQL server settings

```
server-id   = 100 
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log 
expire_logs_days = 12
max_binlog_size = 120M 
binlog-format = row // very very important for read, update and delete
```

Source

```
https://github.com/aliozyildirim/mysql-binlog-reader-and-cdc/
```

Comment: this code records the log from the log database to the cdc database